# Как узнать сколько жестких(или ssd) дисков установлено и какая у них вместимость?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Какой командой узнать сколько физических дисков установлено и какая у них вместимость?
Не смонтированные разделы, а именно физические устройства.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть симпатичная утилитка `lsblk`, обычно присутствует в штатной поставке, которая может нарисовать дерево использования устройств, например:

```
melkij@melkij:~$ lsblk 
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda2           8:2    0   298G  0 part 
│ ├─sysvg-home 254:1    0 186,3G  0 lvm  /home
│ └─sysvg-root 254:0    0    15G  0 lvm  /
└─sda1           8:1    0    94M  0 part /boot
```

У меня стоит 1 диск 320гб (298ГиБ), один раздел на нём смонтирован в `/boot`, поверх второго развёрнут `LVM`

Либо, например, запросить `lsblk --nodeps`

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk
```

Покажет только устройства, но не разделы на них и прочие LVM.

---

Важная оговорка - это всё если устройства распознаны операционной системой и между ними и системой нет ничего дополнительного. Если накопители подключены через RAID контроллер - то обычно система видит только сам контроллер. А какие там на самом деле диски - необходимо уточнять через софт этого контроллера.

Answer (score 8):

`lshw` - list hardware ([тут матчасть](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw)).

```
sudo lshw -class disk
```

Answer (score 1):

Если есть желание обойтись без сторонних утилит, то можно так:

`grep -r . /sys/block/sd?/size`

Размер выводится в 512-байтовых блоках. Также, как и все остальные способы, этот не различает жёсткий диск от флешки или кард ридера.

Comment: *не различает* — понятно же, что всё это **блочные устройства хранения информации**. а как именно они физически реализованы — это уже детали.